# Python: heapq.heappop() gives strange result

Tags: python, heap, heapq

I'm trying to use the Python module `heapq` in my program but I ran into a strange problem using `heapq.heappop()`. The function does not appear to return the smallest element in the heap. Take a look at the following code:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import heapq
>>> list = [[1326, 'a'], [654, 'b']]
>>> print heapq.heappop(list)
[1326, 'a']
>>> print heapq.heappop(list)
[654, 'b']
```

Should `heappop()` not return `[654, 'b']` first and then `[1326, 'a']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ["heapify"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify) the list first (an in-place operation):

```
In [1]: import heapq

In [2]: l = [[1326, 'a'], [654, 'b']]

In [3]: heapq.heapify(l)

In [4]: heapq.heappop(l)
Out[4]: [654, 'b']

In [5]: heapq.heappop(l)
Out[5]: [1326, 'a']
```

And, avoid naming your list as `list` - you are *shadowing* the built-in `list` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem for the above example. For my code I found that each time I edited the heap I needed to use the sort() function again (silly me).